# "click to donate" button

Tags: e-commerce

How exactly do "click to donate" buttons work on websites like http://www.care2.com?

How is money generated? Is it just clicks that is the main source of funds?

Comment: This isn't a programming question ...

Comment: Sorry, can stop smiling. It sounds me like clicking causing money to print. If so, I have a theory, "There is a Matrix that is powered by mouse clicks. For each million click they get 1 MW power. When you click they transfer the money to the care2.com for the power they have got from mouse clicks on care2.com website." (pun intended)

Comment: @Nishant, glad I've put a smile on your face :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect they have some sponsor that pay for X amount of clicks each month. Usually these sponsors are companies, but also private persons sponsor sometimes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect donations on a website then you could use a PayPal donation button.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside

You would then receive the donations into your PayPal account.